# My Access SQL is rejected for a combo box

Tags: sql, combobox

I'm rescuing an Access database, MDB file. For a combo box the "Control Source" is empty, the "Row Source Type" is Table/Query and the "Row Source" is:

```
SELECT [tblProjects].[Project_Number], ([tblClients].[Client]  where [tblClients].[Client Number]=[tblProjects].[Client Number]) from [tblProjects] Order by [tblProjects].[Project_Number]
```

The client number fields are indeed "Client Number". The error message I get is
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '([tblClients].[Client]  where [tblClients].[Client Number]=[tblProjects].[Client Number])'".

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You've an extra ( before tblclients before the where?  And your from and where are back to front `select x from y where z=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My subselect was broken. Should be
SELECT [tblProjects].[Project_Number], (select [tblClients].[Client] from [tblClients] where [tblClients].[Client Number]=[tblProjects].[Client Number]) from [tblProjects] Order by [tblProjects].[Project_Number]

Comment: Look at a join for this too maybe?